# Can "I won't be here" be shortened to "I won't" in the following?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

> Please pretend I'm not here. Actually, I won't (be here.) I'll be in
> the world of this book.

Can *be here* be dropped in this sentence? Or maybe after doing that, the sentence will be grammatically incorrect or ambiguous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could drop "here": "Please pretend I'm not here. Actually, I won't be." But you need "be" since the verb changed tense from "I am" to "I will [not] be."